# C#, WPF, Async GUI update and memory leaks

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private delegate void UpdateTextBoxDelegate(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object     value);
..
UpdateTextBoxDelegate updateTextDelegate = new UpdateTextBoxDelegate(textBox1.SetValue);
..
foreach(..)
    Dispatcher.Invoke(updateTextDelegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { TextBox.TextProperty, content.ToString() });
```

This stuff leaks. I am updating a GUI with some progress information as the task comes along, it is working fine but the content.ToString() in the last line leaks. I can only speculate that through the Dispatcher there is kept a reference to that string until it is destroyed (memory will get released when i Close the dialog that holds it).
It is pretty evident that it IS the strings that gobble up memory just by observing memory usage patterns (starts slow, then inclines to 10meg increments towards the end as the string gets bigger), I've also done a dump of the hanged process (out of memory) and debugged with windbg.. a few traces puts it to many char[]'s and the gui framework textbox etc.)
When I do en explicit SetValue, even async, why is the old content not eligible for garbage collection ?

Advice ? :-)

Comment: "It is pretty evident that it IS the strings that gobble up memory": did you try to use a memory profiler to locate the source of the leak? It might not be what you think...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not worry about the memory if you've released the references, leave rest to garbage collector to do it's job.

Secondly what you can do is to make GC's job easier by limiting the objects to reach in higher generations. GC prefer if an object can be cleaned within first sweep.

more about [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection: Generations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#generations)

the problem for not being collection by garbage collector is the generation of the object

gen 0 are cleared within the first sweep after they are un-referenced

but same will be promoted to gen1 if still referenced while garbage collection sweeps the memory

and to gen 2 and so on

so in order to minimize the promotion you could copy the value to a local variable

example

```
foreach(..)
{
    string value = content.ToString();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(updateTextDelegate, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { TextBox.TextProperty,  value });
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but for the life of me cant figure out why it should be better..If i do the content.ToString in in Invoke it should exists in an even narrower scope than by declaring and assigning it before. Right? I will read up on "the fundamentals of gc" that you provided, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about this, the answer was to build around with a StringBuilder instead of plain string.